# For loop is working differnt on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

forgive me if im being stupid and missing something obvious but i cant wrap my head round this.

I have an array, i want to scroll through the top 10 options, then console log the number when clicked in a list. Google chrome will output the correct number of 0 when its ran as there is only 1 thing in the array but ie will output -1. Ive never seen this before, i even put it in a jsfiddle that outputs the different answer depending on the browser - https://jsfiddle.net/5f5Lssuj/1/

Could someone please open this in ie and chrome, click on the list and confirm. I have to post the code here so here is the script, theres only a ul in the html, heres the js:

```
liveGamesList = ["one"];
console.log(liveGamesList);


var ulist = document.getElementById('lists');

for (let i = (liveGamesList.length - 1); i >= liveGamesList.length - 10; i--) {
    let gameNumber = i;
    console.log("game number is " + i);

    if (liveGamesList[gameNumber]) {
        console.log(i + " is valid!");
        var game = document.createElement('li');
        game.addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log("clicking " + i);
            }
            .bind(this));

        ulist.appendChild(game);
    } else {
        console.log(i + " is not valid, breaking");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: because `let` in internet exploder isn't ES2015 spec `let`, perhaps

Comment: wait so i cant use let in ie? i need to use let in this situation to control the click events otherwise it would reference the same i for every click event

Comment: you need to go old school ... an IIFE ... or break out the body of the for loop into a function ... or, use a transpiler

Comment: that sounds difficult, which is eaiser?

Comment: Neither is more difficult than the other :p